# how to solve name collision between Type Name, Function Name and parameter name?

Tags: c++

for example ,I has this code:

```
struct Range
{
}

struct FooObj
{
     void Range(int x, Range** r){....}     //!< This is OK.
     void Foo(int x, Range** r) {....}      //!< This is Not OK, Why?
}
```

then I fix the function Foo(int,Range**) to:

```
void Foo(int x, struct Range** r){...}
```

The name collision has been solved,But why the function Range() has no name collision?

BTW, I test those code in VS2010.

Comment: Declarations introduce names. The names they introduce are only visible after a specific *point of declaration*. This point is *after* the parameter list for function declarations. Hence, the name `Range` (referring to `Foo::Range`) is only visible after `void Range(int, Range**) /* here */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `::Foo::Range` hides `::Range`. Look at this easier example:

```
int i;

void foo()
{
    int i;

    i = 1; // local variable `i`.
    ::i = 1; // global variable `i`.
}
```

Yes. Q.E.D.

To use `struct Range`, just use `::Range`.

(And you also need to remove `void` of `void Foo(..`. it is constructor. [live example](http://ideone.com/E4Ut6P))

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a forward declaration of Foo::Range (no header file), so at the time Foo::Range is being compiled there is no name collision. But when Foo::Foo is being compiled, Foo::Range has already been declared.